# Error inflating class CoordinatorLayout in real device but emulator worked

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-view

I know someone will respond this question as duplicate. Actually i already search and follow but still got error. In my emulator it working, but when i run in real device, i got that error. I already add dependencies which is
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'`

But still got error. I really don't know how to solve it. I also got this error.

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity

Answer (score 1):

From the stacktrace you can see:

> You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.

Which means, that you have set incorrect theme as your application/activity theme. It should be a descendant of a `Theme.AppCompat`.

Double check your themes.